# How to get a Modelform to show fields in a detail page in Django?

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, django-forms

What I would like to accomplish is that I get the form from songcreate to in same url as the Detail.html so a person can add more songs without having to leave and comeback multiple times.Eventually I hope to do this process with AJAX but haven't advance to that stage yet since i can't get the form to start. I think it may just be something simple but have been unable to pin point what it is.

## Views.py

```
 class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        # form_class = SongCreate
        model = Album
        template_name = 'post/detail.html'
    
        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(SongCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
            return kwargs
        def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
             pk  =self.kwargs.get('pk')
             obj = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=pk)
             return obj
        def get_context_data( self, *args, **kwargs ):
            context =super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            # context['create_form'] = SongCreate()
            # context['create_url'] = reverse_lazy("post:index")
            query = self.request.GET.get("q")
            if query:
                qs = Album.objects.search(query)
            return context
```

This is the Song create view when using its on url. it works just fine but I want to be able to show this form in the detail page or list page if thats not possible.

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
        model = Song
        success_url = reverse_lazy('post:index')
        form_class = SongCreate

        def form_valid(self, form):
            if form.is_valid():
```

----------(Here is validation which ill skip for brevity)--------

```
            return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)

        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(SongCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
            return kwargs
```

So my main problem lies here form some reason I am not able to get the fields to show up in the detail page correctly even though it shows up perfectly in its actual page. When I set it up it only shows me the the outline of the form and the submit button.

## Details.html

```
{% block body %}

      **<!--Form--> HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE FORM-->**
<div class='col-sm-9 '>
     {% if not request.GET.q %}
        <div class=''>

            {% include "post/song_form.html" with form=create_form action_url=create_url btn_title='submit' form_class='SongCreate' %}

        </div>
        <hr/>
    {% endif %}

      <div clas="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" >
               {% for Song in Album.song_set.all %}
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#">
                      {% if object.image %}
                      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
                      {% endif %}
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    {{ song.song_name }}<br/>
                    {{ song.description}}|
                    via {{ Album.timestamp }}
                  </br/>
                    <br>
                 </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Here is my form i used a modelform and it requires you to select the the album and it shows the albums the person has created to you can append it that album then make a description about it.

## Forms.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import  Song
from .models import  Album
from django import forms

class SongCreate(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = [
            'album',
            'song_name',
            'description'
        ]
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(SongCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['album'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

Comment: What is the structure of your templates directory?

Comment: post/base, post/song_form.html, post/form-template, form.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `include "/post/song_form.html"`. Without the preceding slash it might be looking in the local folder of your `details.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing two separate views for your detail view page and your form, you could include the form in the detail view page view.  You could do this by adding a "mixin" `FormMixin`. So you would list your validate and create form logic in your detail view.

Link to docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin)

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

 class DetailView(generic.DetailView,FormMixin):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'post/detail.html'
    form_class = SongCreate

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
         pk  =self.kwargs.get('pk')
         obj = get_object_or_404(Roote, pk=pk)
         return obj
    def get_context_data( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        context =super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # context['create_form'] = SongCreate()
        # context['create_url'] = reverse_lazy("post:index")
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            qs = Album.objects.search(query)
        return context
  **def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I have attempted this a couple of times but get a:  super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type....  In cmd:    kwargs = super(SongCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type could you explain further?

Comment: Maybe try and take out the def get_form_kwargs function and assign the user to the object in the def form_valid function. So in the function just say form.instance.user = self.request.user then return super().form_valid(form) at the bottom. I edited my answer.